# String in list multiplied by item in another list, printed on separate lines

Tags: python, string, list

Basically:

```
list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

And I want my output to be in the form of

```
x
y
y
z
z
z
```

I have

```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
   output = list1[i] * list2[i]
   print(output)
```

But that only gets me

```
x
yy
zzz
```

Comment: Perhaps add what your desired output should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding to the same string each time, but not printing in between. Instead, add another `for` loop:

```
list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for x in list1[i] * list2[i]:
        print(x)
```

This runs as:

```
>>> list1 = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in range(len(list1)):
...     for x in list1[i] * list2[i]:
...         print(x)
... 
x
y
y
z
z
z
>>>
```

Another suggestion, instead of doing `for i in range(0, len(list1)):`, do `for i in range(len(list1))`. Python automatically takes that as `range(0, len(list1))`:

```
>>> range(0, len(list1))
[0, 1, 2]
>>> range(len(list1))
[0, 1, 2]
>>>
```

However, if you want to add a *jump* for the `range()`, you **need** to include the `0`:

```
>>> range(len(list1), 2)
[]
>>> range(0, len(list1), 2)
[0, 2]
>>>
```

**Answering your comment, use list comprehension to multiply the values, and then a `for` loop to print them:**

```
list1 = ['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list1 = [list1[i]*list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
for k in ''.join(list1):
    print k
```

This runs as:

```
>>> list1 = ['xx', 'yy', 'zz']
>>> list2 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list1 = [list1[i]*list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
>>> for k in ''.join(list1):
...     print k
... 
x
x
y
y
y
y
z
z
z
z
z
z
>>> list1
['xx', 'yyyy', 'zzzzzz']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now let's say instead that list1 = ['xx', 'yy', 'zz'] and instead of every _character_ being printed on a new line, I just want every _product_ on a new line, such that the final form would be ['xx', 'yyyy', 'zzzzzz'] printed across three lines. What do I need to do differently?     edit: zip in the answer provided by @goncalopp works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

Take the advantage of `print()` function:

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> for x in map(mul, list1, list2):
    print(*x, sep='\n')
...     
x
y
y
z
z
z
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham This code would still work fine in Python 2.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can be used in Python 2 as well by importing `print_function` from `__future__`.

Comment: @200OK, ah I see, thanks, I was trying to get it to work without importing `print_function`

Answer (score 3):

```
for item, count in zip(list1, list2):
    for _ in range(count):
        print(item)
```

Comment: @wim -- Thanks, that's what I was going for :)

Answer (score 0):

**Your solution is almost correct**, you just need to print each charater of `output` in a new line:

```
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    output = list1[i] * list2[i]
    for character in output:
        print character
```

Let's see if we can make this solution **smaller** and **more pythonic**.

---

In `range(0,len(list1)):`, the `0` is redundant.`range` starts at 0 if only one argument (the end) is provided, so you could simply use `range(len(list1))`.

---

Accessing elements by index is very rarely needed in python. In this particular case, you should use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), to take elements from both lists, one-by-one:

```
for a,b in zip(list1, list2):
    output = a*b
    for character in output:
        print character
```

---

Instead of using a `for` to print each character, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with the newline character:

```
for a,b in zip(list1, list2):
    print "\n".join(a*b)
```

---

You can write this last solution in a single line as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), too:

```
print "\n".join(["\n".join(a*b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)])
```

---

Finally, a more advanced (and arguably less pythonic) solution would use features from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
print "\n".join(chain(*map(repeat, list1, list2)))
```

Comment: FWIW, whenever I see `chain(*...)` I recommend `chain.from_iterable(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

list comprehension:

```
output = [j for i in range(len(list1)) for j in list1[i] * list2[i] ]
for char in output:
    print char
x
y
y
z
z
z
```

One line:

```
print '\n'.join([j for i in range(len(list1)) for j in list1[i] * list2[i]])

x
y
y
z
z
z
```

Comment: Better to use an iterator, much more efficient and putting it all on one line has no merit whatsoever. I would in fact avoid doing code like that.

Comment: @AlexThornton, just showing  the different ways you can do things using Python. There is no need to import anything to achieve the desired output either but there are other answers that have.

Comment: That isn't really any kind of advantage either.

Comment: @AlexThornton, what is no advantage?

Comment: The fact that no imports are needed.

Comment: @AlexThornton, have you timed the other code in the answers?